# How to get the value of selected radio button in action class, struts 2?

Tags: struts2

How to get the value of selected radio button in action class, struts 2?

```
<s:form action="vote.action" method="post">
<s:radio name="vote" list="#{'1':'Candidate1','2':'Candidate2','3':'Candidate3'}" value="2" />
<s:submit method="execute" key="label.vote" align="center" />
```

Comment: The same way as a textfield, with setters in the action with the same name. Anyway it's better to search examples on the internet of what you are trying to do before you ask here, like: http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-sradio-radio-button-example/ =)

Answer (score 2):

In order for struts2 to inject your form values in your action class you need to do one of following things

1. Create individual properties in your action class with same name as field value in your JSP.
2. Create a bean with properties required by you and make sure to name those properties same as the one in your JSP.
3. Create getter and setter for the properties of bean in your action class.

I suggest to go through some of the documents describing how data flows between your JSP and Action class as well in reverse way.

In short for your radio button all you need to do is define getter and setter in your action class with same name as name of the jsp radio button field and you are all set to receive the value in your action class (power and magic of interceptors ;))

[processing-forms](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.4.1/docs/processing-forms.html)